# My .text('') is not replacing the form field data as expected

Tags: jquery

I have an 11 row table with an id=’eliminate’, in which 6 rows have id’s of no. 1-6, the others w/o id’s.

For example:

```
   <tr id="1" style="visibility:<?php if(empty($row_rsUpdate2['teacher_last_name'])) echo 'hidden;'; else echo 'visible;';?>">

  <td><a href="#" id="clear1">clear</a></div></td>
```

There are seven input fields in each row and, since this is an update form, they are fed from the db with existing data. I want the viewer to be able to remove the existing data from the seven form fields in the row, prior to updating, simply by clicking ‘clear’ and to replace it all with empty strings, i.e. ‘’.

I am trying this (and many variations of it,) without success:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 $('#clear1').click(function(){

  $('#eliminate #1 input').text('');    }); });
```

The click function has alerted the form fields correctly (7), so that's not it, other edits and tests have shown some life, but all to no avail. As I am new to jQuery, I’m  chasing my tail today. How do I get the results I want?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use `val()` instead, like so:

```
$('input').val('');
```

This method is special for form elements as a way to change their value, and the above will empty out inputs or textareas. More info over at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/).